# Disable selection range insertion in vim macro

Tags: vim

I want to save vim macro for reuse. Part of what I want to achieve is:

- Make visual selection of part of a line
- Search & replace in it with `:s/\%Vsearch/replace/e`

But the automatic insertion of selection range (`'<,'>`) after `:` is causing me issue. How can I disable it or bypassing it for this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<C-u>`:

```
:<C-u>s/\%Vsearch/replace/e
```

If you want to use `<C-u>` in a saved macro you will need to use its literal notation, `^U`, that you can obtain by typing `<C-v><C-u>` in insert mode.

See `:h i_ctrl-u`.

Comment: Thanks but it works when recording the macro *by hand*… but doesn’t seems to if I try to save it in a file for future use (ie: `let @s = ":<C-u>s/\%Vsearch/replace/e\r"`), which is what I try to achieve.

Comment: It's the same for saved macros: you only have to insert a literal `^U` instead of `<C-u>`: it's done with `<C-v><C-u>`.